# What can I replace 'any' with while declaring an object type in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
class ResistorColor 
{
  private colors: string[]

  public colorValues: any = {
    grey: 8,
    white: 9
  }
}
```

'any' there means Typescript should not care about its type.

I want to replace 'any' by a type. How do we give proper types to such objects in Typescript?

Comment: Remove it entirely and let TS infer it. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCmECWEAuB7ATgYXSL0AUAN6HTQAOmSAbmKvNMHlhAFzRrUB2A5gNoBdQmUoBXAEYgkwJi0wA1MCDGJoAXmily5XpngBPDgA4ANKPIB3ABZIGHAJyiAvoWdA

Comment: So, in these cases it is not possible for the developer to specify a proper type? @zerkms

Comment: It's possible - mouse over it and see the type. You can type the same manually.

Comment: Just as zerkms mentioned, the use of explicit type annotation is not required. TypeScript can infer the variables type for you through Type Inference.

Comment: Which method is better? `any` or letting TS infer it? @zerkms

Comment: I don't have `any` anywhere in my TS code and I hardly can think of any valid use case for `any` that would pass my code review.

Comment: @TannerDolby TS infers the types of the contents of the object, not the object itself. Is this correct?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCmECWEAuB7ATgYXSL0AUAN6HTQAOmSAbmKvNMHlhAFzRrUB2A5gNoBdQmUoBXAEYgkwJi0wA1MCDGIOxXpngBPDtzEBbCfEwBuaAHcAFkgZ7DxzAF9oAXmily5TTo4AOABpRcmtbeA4ATlEnQicgA ?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl letting typescript infer it is much, much better than `any`.  Avoid `any` at all costs! Setting a specific type like `{grey: number; white: number;}` is fine but it's not neccessary.

Comment: @zerkms Please write your last example and the explanation as an answer so that I can select it.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Why do you say avoid any at all costs? Why is it a problem? Please eplain.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl you might want to define your colors as a union of string literals, `type Color = grey | white`.  Then declare `colors` as `Color[]` and `colorValues` as `Record<Color, number>`

Comment: @LindaPaiste Please write an answer and explain your comment there. It is useful.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl `any` means "this variable can be anything".  You have zero information about what the actual type is.  You could set it to any other value of any other type and typescript won't complain.

Comment: "Why is it a problem?" --- the reason people choose TS is to write type safe code. Using `any` makes it unsafe again. What's the point of having TS then.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Alright. I get it.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl If you really wanted to write "safe" code. You could create an interface like `interface Colors { grey: number; white: number; }` and then give your variable a type annotation like `public colorValues: Colors { grey: 8, white: 9 }`

Comment: @TannerDolby Thank you for the information. I request you to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, using `any` as a type annotation in TypeScript doesn't help in writing safe code. It's better to not write a type annotation in that case and let TypeScript infer the type through [Type Inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html).

If you wanted to provide an explicit type annotation for the `colorValues` variable. You could create an interface, which acts as a blueprint to define the properties you expect the object to have.

```
interface Colors {
  grey: number;
  white: number;
}

public colorValues: Colors = {
  grey: 8,
  white: 9
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not want to use `any` except in cases where you absolutely have to.  `any` means that a type can be literally anything so you have no information about what the type is.  Typescript is not able to check for misuse of the variable because you've said "anything goes".

There are many ways to type this properly but here's one idea.  You can define a `type Color` which is the union of the `string` names of all valid colors.  Your `private colors` is an array of these, so it would be `Color[]`.  Your `public colorValues` is a mapping of colors to numbers so you can use the built-in utility type [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to describe it as `Record<Color, number>` which is an object where the keys are type `Color` and the values are type `number`. (If not all colors are present in the object then you would use `Partial<Record<Color, number>>` for an incomplete mapping).

```
type Color = 'grey' | 'white';

class ResistorColor 
{
  private colors: Color[] = []; // initial value avoids "not assigned in the constructor" error

  public colorValues: Record<Color, number> = {
    grey: 8,
    white: 9
  }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w264Vw)

It might make sense to get the `type Colors` from using `typeof` on an array of color names, but I don't know where in your code you would have such an array or object with all of the colors.  This might make sense if, for example, you initialized the `colorValues` with some base value.

```
const colors = ['grey', 'white'] as const; // use as const to preserve string literals

type Color = (typeof colors)[number];  // indexed access by [number] to get the element type
// resolves to: type Color = "grey" | "white"

class ResistorColor {
    public colorValues: Record<Color, number>;

    constructor(baseVal: number = 0) {
        this.colorValues = {} as Record<Color, number>; // need to make an `as` assertion when starting with an incomplete object
        colors.forEach(
            color => this.colorValues[color] = baseVal
        );
    }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/NBzjDN)